# Bind listbox to ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, class, binding, observablecollection

I cannot find an answer I can work with for this problem. 
I have an ObservableCollection

this is myClass:

```
public class myClass
    {
      public string name;
      public int[] dimensions = new int[2];
    }
```

This is the code that sets ObservableCollection:

```
public class roomBuilder
{
  private ObservableCollection<myClass> rooms;

      public roomBuilder() //constructor
      {
        string roomName;
        int[] dimensions = new int[2];
        myClass newRoom = new myClass();
        rooms = new ObservableCollection<room>();
        roomName = "Hall";
        dimensions[0] = 10;
        dimensions[1] = 12;
        newRoom.name = roomName;
        newRoom.dimensions = dimensions;
        rooms.Add(newRoom);
        roomListBox.DataContext = rooms;
      }
```

the XAML for this is:

```
    <ListBox Canvas.Left="-1" Canvas.Top="47" Height="419" Name="roomListBox" Width="481"  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="GhostWhite" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DataContext="{Binding}"> 

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate  >
            <DataTemplate   >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="1" Name="verstack"   > 
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="1" KeyDown="StackPanel_KeyDown" >
                        <TextBox Text="{Binding  Path=name}" IsReadOnly="False" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="22" Height="65" VerticalAlignment="Top" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBox Name="xDimension" Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=dimensions[0] }"  Width="70" Height="65" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsReadOnly="False" FontFamily="Courier New" Margin="2,0,1,0" FontSize="22" MaxLength="3" InputScope="TelephoneNumber" TextAlignment="Center"  />
                    <TextBlock Name="separator" Text=":" FontSize="32"  FontWeight="ExtraBold" Margin="1,4,1,0"  />
                        <TextBox Name="yDimension" Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=dimensions[1] }" Width="70" Height="65" VerticalAlignment="Top"   IsReadOnly="False" FontFamily="Courier New" Margin="1,0,2,0" FontSize="22" MaxLength="3" InputScope="TelephoneNumber" TextAlignment="Center"/>
```

I havent closed the Xaml off here , there's a load more underneath it, when I run this nothing is displayed and I just don't know what the problem is, I've been hammering away at it for 2 days, please someone help

Comment: Read [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)...

Comment: you can compile this code? ObservableCollection<myClass> rooms != rooms = new ObservableCollection<room>(); is it a typo? nevertheless check your output window for dataerrors and be aware of the right datacontext.

Comment: No that orks fine, it's just an odd way I do things. The answer below was the right one, it's something I'm not used to so it sorted me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rooms needs to be a public property that you bind to.

```
public ObservableCollection<myClass> rooms
{ 
   get { return ........
```